# cannot get value from php ajax

Tags: php, json, ajax, html

Cannot get value from php true AJAX.

My php code is

```
<?php
$name =  $_POST['name'];
$hobby = $_POST['hobby'];
if (!empty($name and $hobby)){
echo 'Data was succesfully captured';
}else {
echo 'Data was not captured'
}
```

my html code is

```
<div id="result"></div>

<form method="post">
<input name="name" type="text" id="name">
<br>
<input name="hobby" type="text" id="hobby">
<input name="snd_btn" type="button" id="snd_btn" value="Save">
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#snd_btn').click(function() {
var name = $('#name').val();
var hobby = $('#hobby').val();
$.ajax({
 url: "save.php",
 type: "POST",
dataType: 'json',
data: { name, hobby,
success: function(result) {
$('#result').html(result);
  },
}
 });
 });
   });
```

if i Change in js to

```
success: function() {
$('#result').html('Data was succesfully captured');
},
```

it work but not from php

Comment: What do you mean by true AJAX?

Comment: receive data from php with ajax

Comment: I have answered. Hope this works....

Comment: What is save.php doing ? What output does save.php throwing back to this page ?

Comment: Is `data: { name, hobby,` correct or is this a copy/paste problem?

Comment: Put a semicolon at the end of the line `echo 'Data was not captured'`. Any change?

Comment: Still does not help
Look, maybe I did not explain myself correctly
I'm trying to get a result like from the site here Example : https://www.codexworld.com/post-get-json-data-from-php-script-jquery-ajax/

Comment: When you have a problem like this, the first step to solving it is to break it down into the component parts and isolate where the issue is occurring. Make sure each little bit is working on its own. So in this case, try running the PHP script on its own; ie go to the ajax url directly in the browser and test it without the Javascript to get in the way; this will help you isolate the problem in the PHP code. When you have the PHP code working correctly on its own, then you can test it with the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

This one is wrong.

```
if (!empty($name and $hobby)) {
```

Please replace that with:

```
if (!empty($name) and !empty($hobby)) {
```

You have to check for emptiness of the variable for each one.

Comment: It's okay, but I do not see a success message from php  to result DIV

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have check that the ajax call will be successfully done or not

If ajax call was successfully done then,

Check the response of success data by print the in console.

Your php code should be like this

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$hobby = $_POST['hobby']; 
 if ($name and $hobby ){ 
        echo json_encode('Data was succesfully captured');
     }else {
        echo json_encode('Data was not captured'); 
    }
```

From php you have to return data in form of json.

And js side:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#snd_btn').click(function() { 
        var name = $('#name').val(); 
        var hobby = $('#hobby').val();
        $.ajax({ 
             url: "save.php", 
             type: "POST", 
             dataType: 'json', 
             data: { name:name, hobby:hobby}  // data in { key : value}
             success: function(result) { 
             res = JSON.parse(res);
             console.log(res);// display in developertools > console
                 $('#result').html(res); 
             },
 }); }); });
```

Comment: Your ajax data is not correct

$.ajax({ 
    url: "save.php", 
    type: "POST", 
    dataType: 'json', 
    data: { name:name, hobby:hobby}

Comment: In ajax your data is not in right syntax,
Data should be in the pair of key value

Comment: Ok i will check and tell you

Answer (score 0):

**Problems:**

- After `hobby` comes a "}" before ",".
- Then, you have an error-prone additional "}". The one after the closing "}," (btw, delete the ",") of `success` callback.
- You forgot the semicolon at the end of the line echo 'Data was not captured'.
- The ajax call expects a JSON encoded response, as you defined `dataType: JSON`. So, in PHP, you must encode the response string - with [json_encode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).
- Since you don't have an error callback (`error: function(...){...}`) you can't see any errors. So, define one. An example is below.

**Recommendations:**

- Define the `data` object as below.
- The PHP check on empty values should happen as below.
- You must also check if the posted values are set.
- Don't show any specific error details to the users. Just display a general user-friendly message to them. So, don't do as I did - by printing the error details in the console :-)

---

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title></title>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#snd_btn').click(function () {
                    var name = $('#name').val();
                    var hobby = $('#hobby').val();

                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: 'save.php',
                        data: {
                            'name': name,
                            'hobby': hobby
                        },
                        success: function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            $('#result').html(result);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert('Error! See the console');

                            console.log(textStatus);
                            console.log(errorThrown);
                            console.log(jqXHR);
                        },
                        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                            //...
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="result"></div>

        <form method="post">
            <input name="name" type="text" id="name">
            <br>
            <input name="hobby" type="text" id="hobby">
            <input name="snd_btn" type="button" id="snd_btn" value="Save">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

**save.php:**

```
<?php

/*
 * Check if the values are set.
 * I used here the short "null coalescing operator".
 * Search for it in the link below.
 *
 * @link https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php Comparison Operators.
 */
$name = $_POST['name'] ?? '';
$hobby = $_POST['hobby'] ?? '';

if (!empty($name) && !empty($hobby)) {
    $response = 'Data was succesfully captured';
} else {
    $response = 'Data was not captured';
}

echo json_encode($response);
```